# Retrieving only some part of document

Tags: c#, solr, lucene, solrnet

I have a Solr Search server which I am inserting very large text files, each of which are about 10 MB plain text file.

Fields are as follows:

```
    [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [SolrField("text")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
```

I am able to Add Documents without a problem, when i try to query and retrieve I dont get back the Content field, even though I should. I am getting back `null`.

Why is that happening?

Also, say I have a very large file then I searched for a term, while returning I want to get back only the part the data that query text is present. Is this possible via solr? how/

Comment: Could you give us your schema.xml? Would be interesting to see how `stored` is defined for the text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying to learn Solr and SolrNet at the same time and using example schema with following definition:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Notice that **stored="false"** here because the field is used for searching only and is [a target of multiple copyField operations](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml#L268).

You need to build your own schema that corresponds to what you want to do. You can find a couple of basic ones in the examples from my book (e.g. [here](https://github.com/arafalov/solr-indexing-book/blob/master/published/collection1/conf/schema.xml), or [here](https://github.com/arafalov/solr-indexing-book/blob/master/published/text1/conf/schema.xml))